# List Linkedin AdAccount users api. error: "Invalid value type for parameter accounts"

Tags: php, laravel, http, linkedin-api

I'm trying to call the LinkedIn API for fetch adaccount users.

Documentation links [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/create-and-manage-account-users?view=li-lms-2023-04&tabs=curl#find-ad-account-users-by-accounts) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/account-access-controls?view=li-lms-2023-04&tabs=http#fetch-existing-ad-account-users)

I use Laravel `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http` facade to make the API call.

This is my code:

```php
$response = Http::withHeaders([
               'X-Restli-Protocol-Version' => '2.0.0',
               'LinkedIn-Version' => '202304',
               'Authorization' => 'Bearer xxxxxxxxx',
          ])
           ->baseUrl('https://api.linkedin.com/rest/')
           ->get('adAccountUsers', [
                     'q' => 'accounts', 
                     'accounts' => 'urn:li:sponsoredAccount:509935087'
           ]);
```

The response fail with error:

```json
[
  "message" => "Invalid value type for parameter accounts"
  "status" => 400
]
```

I tried to `urlencode('urn:li:sponsoredAccount:509935087')` but still returns the same error.

I use PHP: "^8.1" and laravel: "^9.11"

Comment: The example requests in the documentation all appear to have the value _not_ URL encoded. What happens if you don't supply these parameters via the array, but append them to the endpoint path directly, explicitly _not_ applying any URL encoding?

Comment: using this code `->get('adAccountUsers?q=accounts&accounts=urn:li:sponsoredAccount:509935087');`
cause an error with status `400` and code: `ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT` and message  `"Invalid query parameters passed to request"`

when encode the accountUrn like this 
`->get('adAccountUsers?q=accounts&accounts=' . urlencode('urn:li:sponsoredAccount:509935087'))`

it returns the previous error `Invalid value type for parameter accounts`

Comment: worked when I removed the X-Restli-Protocol-Version header but I wonder why

Comment: worked with v2. check my answer

Answer (score 0):

it worked when I removed the `X-Restli-Protocol-Version` header

this code worked for me

```php
$response = Http::withHeaders([
               'LinkedIn-Version' => '202304',
               'Authorization' => 'Bearer xxxxxxxxx',
          ])
           ->baseUrl('https://api.linkedin.com/rest/')
           ->get('adAccountUsers', [
                     'q' => 'accounts', 
                     'accounts' => 'urn:li:sponsoredAccount:509935087'
           ]);
```

this is because by default if I didn't mentions the protocol version. it uses the `v1`

to use version 2 we must follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/concepts/protocol-version)

I make it works for version 2 with this code

```php
$accountUrn = 'urn:li:sponsoredAccount:509935087';

$response = Http::withHeaders([
               'X-Restli-Protocol-Version' => '2.0.0',
               'LinkedIn-Version' => '202304',
               'Authorization' => 'Bearer xxxxxxxxx',
          ])
           ->baseUrl('https://api.linkedin.com/rest/')
           ->get('adAccountUsers?q=accounts&accounts=List(' . urlencode($accountUrn) . ')');
```